# Doctrine One To One Unidirectional Error saving child

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I am working in Doctrine 2.6 Not using symfony just working within my own platform. I been searching everywhere on the net and here on stack and every solution I have found is ending in the same error.

Please help

User Entity

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\UniqueConstraint;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="user",uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(name="user_idx", columns={"email"})})
 */
class User
{

/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @var int
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 * @var string
 */
protected $email;

 /**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="UserProfile", mappedBy="user")
 */
protected $profile;
```

Profile entity

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\JoinColumn;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="user_profile")
 */
class UserProfile
{

    /**
     * @var integer
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var User
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User",inversedBy="profile")
     * @JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $user;
```

Usage in Controller

```
    $this->user = $this->entityManager->getRepository('User')->findOneBy(['email' => $login])


    $profile = new \UserProfile();
    $profile
        ->setUser($this->user)
        ->setAccountType(1);

    $this->entityManager->persist($profile);
    $this->entityManager->flush();
```

This is the error generated by doctrine when I try to persist and flush the child entity.

> ( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught Doctrine\ORM\ORMInvalidArgumentException:
>   A new entity was found through the relationship 'UserProfile#user'
>   that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity:
>   User@0000000045b82749000000006e7c58e6. To solve this issue: Either
>   explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity or
>   configure cascade persist this association in the mapping for example
>   @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}). If you cannot find out which
>   entity causes the problem implement 'User#__toString()' to get a clue.
>   in
>   D:\wamp64\coresys\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\ORMInvalidArgumentException.php
>   on line 102
>
> ( ! ) Doctrine\ORM\ORMInvalidArgumentException: A new entity was found
>   through the relationship 'UserProfile#user' that was not configured to
>   cascade persist operations for entity:
>   User@0000000045b82749000000006e7c58e6. To solve this issue: Either
>   explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity or
>   configure cascade persist this association in the mapping for example
>   @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}). If you cannot find out which
>   entity causes the problem implement 'User#__toString()' to get a clue.
>   in
>   D:\wamp64\coresys\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\ORMInvalidArgumentException.php
>   on line 102

I have tried adding cascade={"persist"} on both entities and the following error is the result

> ( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity
>   constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'sales@mk2solutions.com'
>   for key 'user_idx' in
>   D:\wamp64\coresys\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\AbstractMySQLDriver.php
>   on line 55 ( ! )
>   Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\UniqueConstraintViolationException: An
>   exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO user (email,
>   firstName, lastName, password, accessRole, status, createdOn,
>   loggedInOn) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params
>   ["sales@mk2solutions.com", "Matthew", "Chitty", {}, "ROLE_ADMIN",
>   null, null, null]: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation:
>   1062 Duplicate entry 'sales@mk2solutions.com' for key 'user_idx' in
>   D:\wamp64\coresys\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\AbstractMySQLDriver.php
>   on line 55

Comment: It's saying that you are trying to insert the same email, did u try to change the email?
Idk why you are trying to re-insert the data that you get from your db?
Anyway try to add `cascade={"persist"}` only in the `Profile::user ` not in both.

Comment: My bad I mean try to add `cascade={"persist"}` only in the `User::profile ` not in both.

Comment: tried all variations of persist. I believe the problem is lying in the persist and flush operations. I am testing out now and it seems to be working correctly by persisting and flushing the child entity the error seems to go away and the association is intact.

Comment: Can you show `UserProfile#setUser() and …setAccount()` methods? It's strange that you've get `$this->user` from the Entity Manager and it claims that this is new entity.

Comment: Are you detaching something somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was a method in the bridge class I have built that was trying to persist and flush but there was multiple entities in the manager.

Once I removed that and called entity manager persist then flush on the child entity everything worked perfectly.

It is all up and running now.

Answer (score 0):

Change UserProfile::setUser method like this:

```
public function setUser($user) {
  $user->setProfile($this);
  $this->user = $user;
  return $this;
}
```